# How to set ChannelData for a custom message in Telegram?

Tags: c#, botframework, telegram-bot

I want to send a custom message into the Telegram. How can I set the ChannelData property in reply using C#? Should be set a string which is name-valued such as mentioned in this link [CustomMessage](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/channels.html#customtelegrammessages)? Could you provide me a sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It could be stringified json. For example to send a sticker you can use the following code:

```
var channelData = "{";
channelData +=       "'method': 'sendSticker',";
channelData +=       "'parameters':";
channelData +=       "{";
channelData +=          "'sticker':";
channelData +=          "{";
channelData +=             "'url': 'http://www.thisiscolossal.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/120430.gif',"
channelData +=             "'mediaType': 'image/gif'";
channelData +=          "}";
channelData +=        "}";
channelData +=    "}";
var reply = new Activity();
reply.ChannelData = channelData;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could send an string but it's cleaner if you provide the data as a Json Object (JObject); not as a string. Here is some code sample (from my [blog post](http://southworks.com/blog/2016/09/15/sending-facebooks-quick-replies-using-microsoft-bot-framework/)); showing how to send Facebook's quick replies. You need to do something similar for Telegram; crafting the specific object required for it, replacing the names of the properties, etc.

```
var channelData = JObject.FromObject(new
    {
        quick_replies = new dynamic[]
        {
            new
            {
                content_type = "text",
                title = "Blue",
                payload = "DEFINED_PAYLOAD_FOR_PICKING_BLUE",
                image_url = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/developperss/PNG/Blue%20Ball.png"
            },
            new
            {
                content_type = "text",
                title = "Green",
                payload = "DEFINED_PAYLOAD_FOR_PICKING_GREEN",
                image_url = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/developperss/PNG/Green%20Ball.png"
            },
            new
            {
                content_type = "text",
                title = "Red",
                payload = "DEFINED_PAYLOAD_FOR_PICKING_RED",
            }
        }
    });

    reply.ChannelData = channelData;
```